# Couchbase - query is not updated

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I made a filter and filtering the values from the couch-base. Only first time i am able to getting the right filter values, after that it is  returing the previous filter values every time. So i have to clear the cache every time. Please help.

**Here is my query code.**

```
public Query getFilterQuery(final String titles, final String sender,
            final String sysName, final String prosName, final String fromDate,
            final String toDate) {

        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        com.couchbase.lite.View view = database.getView(FILTER_VIEW);
        if (view.getMap() == null) {
            Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
                public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {

                    String type = (String) document.get(AppConstants.KEY_DOC_TYPE); 
                    if (AppConstants.DOC_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(type)) {

                        String message_type = (String) document.get(AppConstants.MESSAGE_TYPE);

                        Log.d("message_type", message_type);
                        if (message_type.equals("task")) {
                            String msgDetails = (String) document.get(AppConstants.MESSAGE_BODY);
                            try {
                                JSONObject msgObj = new JSONObject(msgDetails);
                                DocumentReader documentReader = mApplication
                                        .getDocumentReader(message_type);
                                documentReader.setJsonObject(msgObj);
                                String title = (String) documentReader.getValue("task.title");
                                JSONArray infoArray = (JSONArray) documentReader.getValue("task.info");
                                String taskDate = null;
                                String senderName = null;
                                String processName = null;
                                for (int i = 0; i < infoArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jObject = infoArray
                                            .getJSONObject(i);
                                    String field_label = jObject
                                            .getString(AppConstants.LABEL);

                                    if (field_label.equals(TASK_DATE)) {
                                        taskDate = jObject
                                                .getString(AppConstants.FIELD_VALUE);
                                        Log.d("taskDate", taskDate);
                                    }
                                    if (field_label.equals(SENDER)) {
                                        senderName = jObject
                                                .getString(AppConstants.FIELD_VALUE);
                                    }
                                    if (field_label.equals(PROCESS_NAME)) {
                                        processName = jObject
                                                .getString(AppConstants.FIELD_VALUE);
                                    }
                                }
                                Date dateFrom = null;
                                Date dateTo = null;

                                try {

                                    date = dateFormat.parse(taskDate);
                                    Log.d("taskDate", taskDate);
                                    if (toDate != null && fromDate != null) {
                                        dateTo = dateFormat.parse(toDate);
                                        dateFrom = dateFormat.parse(fromDate);
                                    }

                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                /*if (titles != null && titles.contains(title)) {
                                    emitter.emit(document.get(AppConstants.MESSAGE_ID),document);
                                }*/

                                if (senderName != null && senderName.contains(sender)) {
                                    emitter.emit(document.get(AppConstants.MESSAGE_ID),document);
                                }

                                /*if (processName != null && processName.contains(prosName)) {
                                    emitter.emit(document.get(AppConstants.MESSAGE_ID),document);
                                }*/

                                /*if (date.before(dateTo) && date.after(dateFrom)) {
                                    emitter.emit(document.get(AppConstants.MESSAGE_ID),document);
                                }*/

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            view.setMap(mapper, "1");

        }
        Query query = view.createQuery();
        return query;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Query in Couchbase-lite is split into 2 parts.

1. Setting up the view (basically - the index)
2. Running the query against the view.

You should create you view only once (your mapper) and run queries against it with a search term under startkey and endkey.
You can also do a compound index, which is basically a string compound from several keys and search by it.

If you set the map everytime you run the query-the query will not be updated, as it look at you version argument and it's always set to a string "1".

if you will change it you will get a new index for you query - but it should be used only in dev when you change your view.

Roi.

Comment: Could you give me some code sample, and in my search  there are 6 Strings so how can i use strtKey and endkey with this.

Comment: When you emit your key you can use emit(doc[someKey] +"_" + doc[someKey2], value); after that in you start key you should build your search term like docKey1_docKey2. I will try to write some sample ASAP.